Stuck in the process validate/attest, adding to strict list SPL v2 SOL token
Mint address: 8Vi8Rc3cWzKwcNnC2LkG8DPPrYoMETu1WNGHCfLaudwd
Sorry new ... I am not completely understanding were to submit these questions and how to get on strict list.
https://github.com/jup-ag/token-list/blob/main/pull_request_template.md
